# How to convert array to int in functional python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I make a primes detector from user input to array, but i can't convert array to int for detect every number

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]

def isPrimer(a):
    Prime = True
    if n >= 2:
        if a % n == 0 :
            Prime = False
    else:
        Prime = False
    return Prime

print(isPrimer(a))
```

and here is my output:

Enter number of elements : 3

Enter the numbers : 10 11 12

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/firmanpraadita/PycharmProjects/PemFungsional/kegiatan_1.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(isPrimer(a))
  File "/Users/firmanpraadita/PycharmProjects/PemFungsional/kegiatan_1.py", line 8, in isPrimer
    if a % n == 0 :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: You need to iterate over the items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list:

```py
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]

def isPrimer(a):
    Prime = True
    if n >= 2:
        if a % n == 0 :
            Prime = False
    else:
        Prime = False
    return Prime

for item in a:
    print(isPrimer(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

An array/list cannot be 'converted' to an int since it only aggregates the elements.
However, you can iterate over the elements and, assuming these elements are integers, run the same code.

```
def isPrimer(a):
Prime = True
if n >= 2:
    for element in a:
        if element % n == 0 :
            Prime = False
else:
    Prime = False
return Prime
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate over the list try this

```
#%%
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]
def isPrimer(a):
    Prime = True
    if n >= 2:
        for x in a : # you have to iterate over elements of your list
            if x % n == 0 :
                print("this number is prime: ",x) #yes thats prime number
                Prime = True
    else:
        Prime = False
    return Prime

print(isPrimer(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `a` is `List[int]`. You need to operate on the elements of the list, not the whole list itself. We can achieve that by making `isPrimer` operate on a single integer. Then apply that function to each element in the array.

```
def isPrimer(p: int) -> bool:
    ...

result = map(isPrimer, a)
for num, is_prime in zip(a, result):
    print(f"is {num} prime? {is_prime}")
```